# number of independent energy-storage elements in this circuit?

Tags: modeling

So I practiced various examples of modeling electrical cricuits and mehanical circuits. I stumbled upon this one:

[image]

and it's same as this:
[image]

now with these direct substitutions: $$k=\frac{1}{L},\;B=\frac{1}{R},\;J=C,\;T_{(t)}=i_{g(t)}$$
I get these equations:
$$i_g=i_{l1}+i_{l2}$$
$$i_{R2}=i_{l2}$$
$$i_c=(i_{R2}+i_{l1})-i_{R1}$$

I get this circuit:
[image]

Now, which number of independent energy-storage elements is in this circuit? Which order is differential equation which describes this circuit and how it looks like? I got this:
$$i_{g(t)}=i c+i_{R1}=C \cdot \frac{d uc}{d t}+i_{R1}=C \cdot \frac{d u_c}{d t}+\frac{uc}{R{1}}$$
Is this differential equation which describes this circuit?

Comment: It's clear right off the bat that the equation is missing something, because the inductor elements are not considered at all. Consider [this technique](https://chic.caltech.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Final-Paper.pdf) for efficient analysis in lieu of writing differential equations; it scales very well to the three storage elements in your design.

Comment: Since a **current** source is driving the two parallel branches, the current of the two inductors are related by the **algebraic** equation, \$i_{L1}+i_{L2}=ig\$. So I would say that the two inductors together contribute only one effective energy storing element. Also, how sure are you about the correctness of the mechanical to electrical conversion?

Comment: @AJN to be honest with you I'm not sure for it but anyway, regardless of mehanical to electrical conversion, I wonder how this electrical circuit can be solved and ofcourse if someone sees that this conversion is incorrect it would be nice to notify abot mistake.

Comment: WTH does this mean? You're applying a torque to an inductor?